# Debugging a React App and ASP.Net MVC 5 API in VS 2019

Tags: c#, asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-mvc

Is there a simple way to start the React dev server (`react-scripts start`) and debug a back-end ASP.Net MVC 5 app at the same time in Visual Studio 2019?

With ASP.Net Core, it's a simple call to `spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");`, but this isn't available in .Net Framework 4.6.

Currently, I can go to the ClientApp folder in my solution, go to the command line and run `npm start` which will start the React dev server on http://localhost:3000. Any of the AJAX calls end up going to the same port, but the backend is running in IISExpress on a completely different port.

Comment: are they going to be deployed that way? sounds like you need to setup your proxy correctly https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/

Comment: I was able to get the proxy option to work when making calls to /api/[controller]. The question is now: How do I automatically run `npm start` and use the React app home page when starting the IISExpress debugger?

Comment: I don't have any specific tips for that.. but what are you trying to debug exactly? it's probably best to think of client and server as two separate things and debug them independently